# How to find the reasoning behind IntelliJ Kotlin lint check

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, lint

I received a lint message while writing Kotlin using IntelliJ as my IDE: `The argument can be converted to 'Set' to improve performance`

My code went something like this:

`val variable3 = variable1 - variable2` variables are of type `List<Int>`

The linter recommended me to change it to `val variable3 = variable1 - variable2.toSet()`

I would like to find out why it recommends this change and where the documentation is so next time I can look up the messages and learn the reasoning behind the lint check.

Comment: I don't know, where the rule is written (yet/bad (seo)indexed!?), but it is probably due to the "nature" of `-` (minus) operator!?;)

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/minus.html ... It is a "Cartesian substraction" and produces for a set(no index, no duplicates) the same results as for list(indexed,dups. possible)...but more efficient (#dups. less operations)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hover over and open the documentation like this:[image]

The general quick fix options can be found and turn on/off under
settings -> inspections -> kotlin (example)

Answer (score 12):

This is about performance and efficiency — in particular, about how the performance *scales* as your data gets bigger.

The `-` operator calls the standard library's [`Iterable<T>.minus(elements: Iterable<T>)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/minus.html) extension function. If you look at its code (which you can do in IntelliJ), you'll see that that works by taking the first iterable (`variable1` in this case) and filtering it to keep only the values *not* in the second one (`variable2`).

How does it check whether an element is in the second one? By calling its [`contains()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/contains.html) method. But how *that* works will depend on the type of iterable. Most `Set`s, for example, can look up by hash code, which takes a short time, regardless of how big the set is.

However, most `List`s and other iterables can't do that: they need to search through the whole list, element by element. How long that takes will obviously depend on the size of the list — it'll be very quick for short lists, but it might take some time to search through a list with thousands or millions of elements.

What makes it particularly important in this case is that it has to do that search repeatedly: once for each element of the first one. So the time can really mount up.

Say that the first iterable has  elements, and the second has . The subtraction has to make  checks; if the second one is a set, then each check takes about the same time, so the overall time is proportional to . But if not, then each check will take time proportional to , so the overall time is × — which can get very big very fast! (For example, if you make each list 10× bigger, it'll take 100× as long.)

So if you don't want your program to grind to a halt when it starts handling more data, it can be well worth converting the second list to a set first. For small amounts of data, it adds a little extra work, but that probably won't be noticeable; and for large amounts of data, it can be a really big win.

That's why the IntelliJ inspection suggests it.

---

<sup>(For those of you who know about algorithmic complexity, please forgive the simplifications I've made here :)</sup>

---

Interestingly, when I tried it myself (in IntelliJ 2021.2.3 with Kotlin v1.5.73), it didn't make that suggestion. And looking into that implementation of the standard library, I see that in some cases the `minus()` method will do the conversion for you! However, I think it doesn't cover some other common cases, so it's still worth doing the conversion yourself if you think the lists could get big.

Comment: I figured out how to see the code in IntelliJ. On mac `command-click` the minus operator (`-`) or on other OSs `control-click`. Thanks, @gidds, your post gave me a lot of insight into why this lint exists. I did not know `Set` was using a hash O(1) lookup before. That is a major performance improvement over O(n). After looking at the code it looks like Kotlin automatically converts `List`s to `Set`.

Comment: Not _every_ Set implementation has (1) lookups. (For example, I wrote one using a simple array, like `ArrayList`; most operations are (), but it's intended for large numbers of tiny sets, where the reduction in memory and low constant factor dominate.) And even `HashSet` can suffer bad performance if the hash function is pathological. But yes, in _most_ cases you can expect sets to have a constant-time lookup, which most lists don't.

Comment: Also, my quick look through the stdlib code suggested that it only converts to a set in _some_ circumstances. So it may still be worth doing the conversion yourself in cases where performance could be an issue.